# How to dynamicaly replace part of a facebook share link with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax, facebook

I have the following interesting situation... im trying to create a modification in the share button link of facebook so that a small part is replaced by a userid number in such manner that when the person click in the shared link it goes to the respective user that shared the data load from my website php file.

i managed to make it work with a user number... but im not being able to substitute it using

this is in my script

`document.getElementById("cliente").innerHTML = myObj.cliente;`

and this is the working version where user id is 22

```html
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://energycycle.com.br/minhaeconomia.php?userid=22#" data-layout="button_count" data-size="large">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fenergycycle.com.br%2Fminhaeconomia.php%3Fuserid%3D22%23&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Compartilhar</a>
</div>
```

so basically i need to substitute the 22 the two times it appear in this code... by the client number that i receive from the microcontroler esp8266.

if you visit this page https://www.energycycle.com.br/minhaeconomia.php?userid=22 you can see the output that the pearson that clicked the shared link will see. is a php page that takes the userid and show the values from a database..

i tried the following but gives errors

```html
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://energycycle.com.br/minhaeconomia.php?userid=id=" cliente "#" data-layout="button_count" data-size="large">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fenergycycle.com.br%2Fminhaeconomia.php%3Fuserid%3Did=" cliente "%23&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Compartilhar</a>
</div>
```

how i can make this replace by id work in this case please help

on the website side its working with inline

`<?php echo $client?>`

as you see here

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://energycycle.com.br/minhaeconomia.php?userid=<?php echo $userid ?>#" data-layout="button_count" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fenergycycle.com.br%2Fminhaeconomia.php%3Fuserid%3D<?php echo $userid ?>%23&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Compartilhar</a>
</div>
```

But i didnt manage to make the php work on the controller..

Thanks in advance. Hope you like the question

Comment: I got it to partially work by getting the whole <div class from the facebook button to be substituted by the getElementById.. however the button is broken now.. it shows only the link...

Comment: ` document.getElementById("cliente").innerHTML = '<div class="fb-share-button" data-layout="button_count" data-size="large" data-href="https://energycycle.com.br/minhaeconomia.php?userid='+myObj.cliente+'#"> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fenergycycle.com.br%2Fminhaeconomia.php%3Fuserid%3D'+myObj.cliente+'%23&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Compartilhar</a></div>';`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem but still have another problem but open another question to try to solve it.

the solution to this question i made here i found by using this:

```
document.getElementById("cliente").innerHTML = '<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://energycycle.com.br/minhaeconomia.php?userid=' + myObj.cliente + '#" + data-layout="button_count" data-size="large" ><a  target="_blank" data-layout="button_count"  data-size="large" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fenergycycle.com.br%2Fminhaeconomia.php%3Fuserid%3D' + myObj.cliente + '%23&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Compartilhar</a></div>';
```

and having this where the button must appear

`<div class="fb-share-button" id="cliente" data-layout="button_count" data-size="large" ></div>`

however in my case it still need some tweek because im getting this values from a get request and it takes a while to receive the numbers and after the numbers are received and populate the fields the button disappear and become a simple underlined word with link.. thats because the button is loading before the innerhtml can act..

now i need to know how to solve this.. how to reload the button after the info is received from the get request.

thanks in advance